# Exchange of derivation and integration

Tags: integration, analysis

$\Omega$ is bounded open subset of $R^n$.  I want to exchange the $\partial_x$ and $\int_\Omega$ in 
$\partial_x\int_\Omega\Psi(z-x)f(z)dz$,
that 
$$
\partial_x\int_\Omega\Psi(z-x)f(z)dz=\int_\Omega\partial_x\Psi(z-x)f(z)dz
$$

What is the condition making above equality right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the measure theory version of [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement) (a.k.a. *differentiation under the integral sign*).

It basically states that if the integral over the function is well-defined *(1)*, the derivative of the function is well-defined (i.e exists) *(2)* and there exists an integrable bound $\Phi:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ of the derivative, i.e. in your case
$$|\partial_x\Psi(z-x)f(z)|\leq\Phi(z)\qquad \text{for a.e. }z\text{ and all }x,\tag{3}$$
then you can do exactly what you wanted, i.e.
$$\partial_x\int_\Omega\Psi(z-x)f(z)dz=\int_\Omega\partial_x\Psi(z-x)f(z)dz.$$

Comment: Could give some hint about the proof ?Or some reference? Thanks very much.

Comment: I have found answer in your link,thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's the same as saying that the integral exists or that the function is Lebesgue-integrable. (I guess you're using Lebesgue-measure.) Proof is done by using dominated convergence theorem - hence condition (3). I see you've found the link. For the proof look at "[Proof of basic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Proof_of_basic_form)" which you can use as a guideline. Wikipedia also hints at an easier proof with Fubini's theorem together with a JSTOR-reference. I just looked up which proof I saw when I learned this first and it's the one using dominated convergence.